# what are mapbase and membase members of UART 8250 port structure?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to understand the 8250 serial port on pci express bus of our board by going through the driver code and I am having hard time understanding the below two members of `struct uart_8250_port`

```
struct uart_8250_port x;
memset(&x, 0, sizeof(x));
....
....
x.port.regshift = 0;
x.port.iotype = UPIO_MEM;
x.port.flags = UPF_SHARE_IRQ | UPF_LOW_LATENCY;
x.port.membase = raw_address;
x.port.mapbase = ioremap(raw_address);
```

What are the members `membase` and `mapbase`? Also, why does `membase` take physical pci bar address whereas `mapbase` takes address returned from `ioremap` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mapbase` is basically a *bus* address of the port register space in the question. `membase` is the same address in CPU virtual address space for memory mapped IO (MMIO) and `iobase` is the similar for IO.

Yes, you may already notice that in your example you have a mistake, i.e. `membase` and `mapbase` should be exchanged.

`mapbase` address is needed to do, for example, DMA operations on top of UART hardware since DMA operates with *bus* addresses.